# How to apply a copy command in a CmakeLists file

Tags: c++, file, cmake, copy

here is my CMakeLists.txt file which is exists in the current directory project1
in the project1 directory, I have a **src** directory which contains the source and headers files. I have the **build** directory.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

#Declaration du projet

project(MYfirstcamke)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

#Inclusion de opencv

include_directories(/usr/local/include/)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

file(

    GLOB_RECURSE

    source_files

    src/*


)
#declaration de l'executable

add_executable(

my_executable

${source_files}

)
#Configuration de l'edition de lien.
target_link_libraries(

my_executable opencv_core  opencv_imgproc opencv_video opencv_highgui


)
```

before, the file command I need to copy the *.cpp and *.hpp in src directory that exist the current directory. I write this code:

```
file(GLOB MY_PUBLIC_HEADERS

  "*.hpp"
)
file(GLOB MY_PUBLIC_SOURCE

  "*.cpp"
)
file(COPY ${MY_PUBLIC_SOURCE} DESTINATION "src/")
file(COPY ${MY_PUBLIC_HEADERS} DESTINATION "src/")
```

when I start the cmake.. where the current directory is **build**. *.hpp and *.cpp are copied to src but the problem here is, src is also copied to **build** and cmake does not work in this case. I need that src rest in the project1 directory. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You are doing weird things. What problem are you trying to solve in first place? Why not place you headers and sources in `src/` manually?

Comment: I bet it's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Please state what you have in mind. In general you must have good arguments to copy source files.

Comment: Assume `<source-dir>` is source dir of your project (where CMakeLists.txt is placed), `<build-dir>` is binary directory (where `cmake` is executed) and  files `<source-dir>/my_source.cpp` and `<source-dir>/my_header.hpp`. Then your second script (placed at `<source-dir>/CMakeLists.txt`) will copy files to `<build-dir>/src/my_source.cpp` and `<build-dir>/src/my_header.hpp` correspondingly. No other files or directories will be created under `<build-dir>/src/` directory.